# Custom Message Body Writer for Jersey Application in Spring

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I have a Rest Api that uses Spring MVC and Jersey

```
@GET
@Path("/hello")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<AccountEntity> hello() {
    return repository.findAll();

}
```

This Method is failing with the following error always

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<net.viralpatel.spring.controller.AccountEntity>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
```

My Gradle Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.9.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: '4.3.9.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.11.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.2.10.Final'
    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1"
    compile "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
    compile 'org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-servlet-server:2.3.11@jar'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey.contribs', name: 'jersey-spring', version: '1.19.4'

}
```

I tried adding

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-moxy', version: '2.26-b06'
```

But then the error appeared as `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;`

[image: My Project Structure]

Update After adding jackson dependency

```
caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<net.viralpatel.spring.controller.AccountEntity>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
```

Comment: Problem is from jersey version only.

Comment: how do i change than i tried that 2 how to change the jersey version in spring mvc

Comment: can you try once with `jackson`? remove `jersey` dependency and add this: `compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.7.0-rc1'`

Comment: You use @RequestBody and search this keyword and HTTP Request, Response.

Comment: i want to use jersey not spring for the same

Comment: @RamanSahasi which jersey dependency can you please point

Comment: @Rahul I'm not sure which version of jersey would be compatible with Spring 4.3.

Comment: @RamanSahasi :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `jersey-json` dependency instead of `moxy` or `jackson`:

```
compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.19.4'
```

This dependency already contains `jackson` in it with other required dependencies.